# What characters need to be escaped for JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, python, json, parsing, escaping

I notice that you can't save `1B` (escape) in json for JSON.parse function you will got `SyntaxError: Unexpected token` (in google chrome) you need to write it as unicde `\u001b`. I'm have json_serialize function wiritten in Python what other characters in strings I need to escape? Here is my python function

```
def json_serialize(obj):
    result = ''
    t = type(obj)
    if t == types.StringType:
        result += '"%s"' % obj.replace('\\', '\\\\').replace('"', '\\"').replace('\n', '\\n').replace('\t', '\\t')
    elif t == types.NoneType:
        result += 'null'
    elif t == types.IntType or t == types.FloatType:
        result += str(obj)
    elif t == types.LongType:
        result += str(int(obj))
    elif t == types.TupleType:
        result += '[' + ','.join(map(json_serialize, list(obj))) + ']'
    elif t == types.ListType:
        result += '[' + ','.join(map(json_serialize, obj)) + ']'
    elif t == types.DictType:
        array = ['"%s":%s' % (k,json_serialize(v)) for k,v in obj.iteritems()]
        result += '{' + ','.join(array) + '}'
    else:
        result += '"unknown type - ' + type(obj).__name__ + '"'
    return result
```

Comment: So why do you do this yourself rather than using the `json` module?

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of using the built-in `json` library?

Comment: @zhangyangyu I use old version of Python on the server that don't have that library and I can't use simple json because I can't install anything there.

Comment: What a bad circumstance! :(@jcubic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I need to escape all control characters < 32. here is my escape function:

```
def escape(str):
    str = str.replace('\\', '\\\\').replace('"', '\\"').replace('\n', '\\n').
        replace('\t', '\\t')
    result = []
    for ch in str:
        n = ord(ch)
        if n < 32:
            h = hex(n).replace('0x', '')
            result += ['\\u%s%s' % ('0'*(4-len(h)), h)]
        else:
            result += [ch]
    return ''.join(result)
```